# Could not create the Java Virtual Machine Error

Tags: java, linux, burp

I'm trying to run this command on my linux machine:

`java -noverify -Xbootclasspath/p:burp-loader-keygen-2020_2.jar -jar burpsuite_pro_v2020.2.jar`

and i keep getting these errors:

```
-Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I tried to install again these versions:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jdk -y
sudo apt install default-jre -y
```

But i kept getting the same error over and over, any solution or help or suggestion?

Comment: Check `java -version`. What do you get?

Comment: I get this:
```openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mix$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the Burp Suite JAR file the wrong way.

- If this is an older version of Burp Suite, you must use Java 8 which still supports the `-Xbootclasspath` option.  Note it is not sufficient to simply install Java 8.  You need to make sure that `java -version` says it is Java 8, or use the full path to the Java 8 version of the `java`
  command.

  This won't work with Burp Suite 2020.4 or later.
- Conversely, if you are using Burp Suite 2020.4 or later, then you need to use Java 9 or later, and you need to run like this:

  ```
  java -jar -Xmx4g /path/to/burp.jar
  ```

Source:

- [Burp Suite Releases: Professional / Community 2020.4](https://portswigger.net/burp/releases/professional-community-2020-4)
- [Launching Burp Suite from the command line](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/getting-started/launching/command-line) (as of the time of writing this answer).